# Run two instance of a windows software

Tags: windows, wine

What are the possibilities of running multiple copies of windows10 software natively?

Open to using linux  wine like container too. Any pointer please?

Comment: On the same machine at the same time? Virtual machines.

Comment: Some software will automatically run separate instances, others would require a different app signature, coded in before compile - for which VMs would be the only way.

Comment: Agreed! Its just that VMs would be over kill. anything like a container would be perfect and easy to use.

Comment: Your phrasing of this question is unclear. Are you talking about running two separate instances of Windows itself, or are you talking about running two copies of some specific program designed for use on Windows, such as Word or Wordpad?

Comment: This is already offered through Windows Sandbox

Comment: Wine is single threaded and rarely a contender for a question like this one.  Great program but doesn't play well with multiple threads.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin  talking about running two copies of some specific program. The program I want to run checks if any other instance is running or not, if running brings that to foreground.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows sandbox is not persistent

Comment: If the program doesn't want to allow two copies of itself to run, you are likely going to have to run a VM to get the second copy running.

Comment: @user1263746 -You wanted native container functionality never said it had to be persistent